# MYSQL connection limit reached - Do JDBC's close automatically?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, xampp, database-connection

I have a few computers that are running a local script but need to be able to communicate information between them.  I am using a MYSQL database on one of the computers with XAMPP to accomplish this.

Each computer repeatedly starts and kills the local script it is running which has a static database class which creates a connection using JDBC on initialization.  They then use this connection to preform actions for about 10-15 minutes before the script is terminated and then restarted.

There are only 5 computers which have access to the MYSQL database and my max_connections is set to 151 but every once and a while I get a connection limit reached error and all my scripts crash.

I assume that MSQL database connection close automatically when the script is terminated because I can run the scripts far more than 151 times before this error occurs.  Do I need to close the connections before I terminate the scripts?  What could be causing this to occur?

Also, I can simply restart the scripts when this error occurs and they start back up fine.  I do not need to go to phpMyAdmin and flush.

Comment: You should always close connections yourself, don't rely on cleanup or destruction on exit. It may take a while (or, if there are bugs could even hang).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you are disconnecting the DB when you finish using it. Some times it takes a while to auto disconnect the session.

Comment: Okay.  If that is what is causing this that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

You should always close the connection when you are done with it as a best practice. In Java if you neglect to close the connection then you will end up with an open connection; however, the documentation for PHP suggests an unclosed connection will be closed when the script completes: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

You can monitor the open connections via your MySQL Workbench or equivalent tool and find where they are coming from as well.